# How to disable System.Security.Cryptography in VS hints?

Tags: visual-studio

Accidentally clicked somewhere and now fly out different "X509, X500"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2IFI.png)

Comment: Welcome! As far as I can remember disabling the button in the lower left corner in your IntelliSense context menu  (```Add items from unimported namespaces```) should do the trick.

Comment: It work!!! Thanks!!!))